# Specifying non-standard library path

Tags: ros, library, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I specify a non-standard library path while building a standard ROS package?

I tried:

```
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/hdf5/lib/' rosmake pcl
```

which did not work.

Archlinux
2.6.39-ARCH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10548/specifying-non-standard-library-path/) by [DavidS](https://answers.ros.org/users/813/davids/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a `link_directories(/usr/local/hdf5/lib)` entry to the package's CMakeLists.txt.

Depending on the library you look for, there might be a nice CMake way (instead of hardcoding):
[CMake libraries](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

I'm not aware of a nice ROS way similar to rosdep.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you're using gcc, try this:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hdf5/lib rosmake pcl
```

If there are shared libraries in there, you'll also need to add that directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime to execute programs that link against `hdf5`.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using environmental variables does not appear to work...

In the end, I had to change CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [DavidS](https://answers.ros.org/users/813/davids/) with karma: 66 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1